# Is it possible to get the user suspension status based on an organization?

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-provisioning-api

I have a need to look up the suspension status of all users within an organization. Unfortunately, OrganizationService.RetrieveAllOrganizationUsers() does not provide us with the suspension information.

I can get a collection of AppsExtendedEntry based on the results of the above method, and iterate through it calling AppService.RetrieveUser(), but that is very slow and extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get that data would probably be:

1) grab all users in instance via Org API call:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_organization_users_experimental

2) grab all users in instance via multidomain API call:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_users_experimental

3) filter the list of users from step 1 down to the specific org you want to use.

4) filter the list of users from step 3 down to suspended users by cross referencing the user in the list of users from step 2.

Jay